# Simple Relay Oscillator

Tags: led, relay, oscillator

In this case the Led blinks,
[image]

[image]

In this case the led just glows

I've committed some terrible mistake, please educate me.

Comment: What is the current you need through your relay to make it switch?

Comment: Woah....so the resistance blocks the current....but why is the led shining?

Comment: You may change the second circuit to make the current for the LED to flow only through the resistor and the LED, but not through the relais coil.  
Just connect the right end of the resistor to the upper contact of the relais only. The lower terminal of the relais coil is connected to the minus pole of the battery only.

Comment: Thank for you describing how it's not working, but you should also state what you are trying to accomplish (What is the goal of your circuit?). Edit your question to help us help you better.

Comment: Oscillation...I want the led to blink

Comment: So as I understand it, the first circuit works fine for you, and you only want to know why the second circuit doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

> Woah....so the resistance blocks the current....but why is the led
>   shining?

The LED shines because there is current (a low value) always passing through it - the relay doesn't receive enough current to force a changeover so you basically have a circuit that does nothing except dimly illuminate an LED.

Answer (score 0):

*I've committed some terrible mistake* Why, what behavior did you expect?

The behavior you describe is to be expected.

In the first circuit the relay cuts off it's own power so it switches off, which restores power which makes it switch it off again...

In the 2nd circuit the current is **too low** to make the relay switch on so it never does. The current is too low due to the series resistor needed to limit the current for the LED. Relays usually need significantly more current than small LEDs.

Comment: _"Why, what behavior did you expect?_ Ahh..That's just to prevent down-votes. I previously asked a question, and people thought that it was dumb and I got Some Down-votes :(..Ohh man ...thank you for your answer

Comment: Will it work, if I amplify the current using a transistor?

Comment: Hmm, that will not be that easy, it depends on what you want to achieve if a transistor will be useful or not. You could also increase the current by adding an extra resistor in parallel with the LED+resistor. But that's wasteful as it just "dumps" the current. The first circuit is the simplest if you just want to flash a LED using a relay.